# h1 not showing in iPhone web app

Tags: jquery, iphone

**Update:** problem was caused by loading wrong page in browser. Solved now.

In the image you can see the front page of an iPhone webpage I am developing using the O'Reilly book by Jonathan Stark. The image shows  iphone.html (see below) which is just a bunch of links, which, when clicked will load the content from index.html (see below) using the ajax in the jquery.js (see below).  A live version of the site is available at www.quoraquora.com

At the very bottom of the jquery file, there is a function which removes the content of the h2 and puts it in the h1. The operative code is this.

```
var title = $('h2').html() || 'Hello!';
    $('h1').html(title);
    $('h2').remove();
    $('#progress').remove();
    }
```

So if you were to click "About" link, then "About" will appear in the toolbar. On the first page, it's supposed to show "hello" because none of the links will be clicked.

However, as you can see in my image, there is no "h1" saying "hello" and when I click on the links, there is no "h1" showing the "About" in the header etc.

Can you tell me why?

[image: iphone with no headers]

HTML

**iphone.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jonathan Stark</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="myCustomIcon.png" /> -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="myCustomIcon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="myCustomStartupGraphic.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="iphone.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Jonathan Stark</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jonathan Stark</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iphone.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" />
        <!--[if IE]> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="explorer.css" media="all" /> 
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="iphone.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1><a href="./">Jonathan Stark</a></h1>
                <div id="utility">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="consulting-clinic.html">Consulting Clinic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="on-call.html">On Call</a></li>
                        <li><a href="development.html">Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p>Jonathan Stark is a web developer, speaker, and author. His consulting firm, Jonathan Stark Consulting, Inc., has attracted clients such as Staples, Turner Broadcasting, and the PGA Tour. ...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <img alt="Manga Portrait of Jonathan Stark" src="images/manga.png"/>
                <p>Jonathan Stark is a mobile and web application developer who the Wall Street Journal has called an expert on publishing desktop data to the web.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="subtle">Jonathan Stark Consulting, Inc.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #222;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#999));
    border-color: #666;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}
#header h1 {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    max-width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li a {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    color: #222222;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
ul li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
ul li a:active,ul li a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
#content a {
    color: blue;
}
#progress {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 80px;
    left: 60px;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 120px;
    width: 200px;
}
#header div.leftButton {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0px -1px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 6px;
    max-width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border-width: 0 8px 0 14px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(images/back_button.png) 0 8 0 14;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#header div.leftButton.clicked {
    -webkit-border-image: url(images/back_button_clicked.png) 0 8 0 14;
}
```

JQuery

```
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 480) {
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#header ul').addClass('hide'); 
        $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>');
    }); 
    function toggleMenu() {
        $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide'); 
        $('#header .leftButton').toggleClass('pressed');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
loadPage();
});
function loadPage(url) {
$('body').append('<div id="progress">Loading...</div>');
scrollTo(0,0);
if (url == undefined) {
$('#container').load('index.html #header ul', hijackLinks);
} else {
$('#container').load(url + ' #content', hijackLinks);
}
}
function hijackLinks() {
$('#container a').click(function(e){
var url = e.target.href;
if (url.match(/quoraquora.com/)) {
e.preventDefault();
loadPage(e.target.href);
}
});
var title = $('h2').html() || 'Hello!';
$('h1').html(title);
$('h2').remove();
$('#progress').remove();
}
```

RE: Is this how I'd use setTimeout starting from $(document) ready until it removes the h2?

```
function hijackLinks() {
    $('#container a').click(function(e){
    var url = e.target.href;
    if (url.match(/quoraquora.com/)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadPage(e.target.href);
    }
    });
    var title = $('h2').html() || 'Hello!';
   $(document).ready
   (
    function() 
       { 
         setTimeout
           (
             function() 
              { 
               $('h1').html(title);
              },
              5000
           );
        }
    );

    $('h2').remove();
    $('#progress').remove();
    }
```

Comment: Try running that code (that change headers) with `setTimeout` e.g.  half a second after `load` is completed, maybe jQuery didn't have chance the process the new DOM of the container.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. thanks for the suggestion. As I'm a newbie who's never programmed any of my own code, I'm not sure if (a) I understood the exact place setTimeout should be implemented and (b) whether my code is correct even if I did get the right place. I did an edit at the bottom of my OP (starting from $(document).ready etc trying to implement it. Is that what you had in mind? If you have edit suggestions, i'd be grateful if you could put them in an answer.

Comment: nope, see my answer can't post nice code in comment. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try having such code instead:

```
function hijackLinks() {
    $('#container a').click(function(e) {
        var url = e.target.href;
        if (url.match(/quoraquora.com/)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            loadPage(e.target.href);
        }
    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("delayed function started");
        var title = $('h2').html() || 'Hello!';
        alert("title: " + title);
        alert("H1 count: " + $('h1').length);
        $('h1').html(title);
        $('h2').remove();
        $('#progress').remove();
    }, 500);
}
```

Reason behind this: maybe jQuery didn't have chance to process the new DOM of the container so give it some time.

Edit: alerts added for debugging the problem.

Comment: Thanks,I'll give it a try.  is that really supposed to be 500? I thought 5 seconds was 5000?

Comment: sadly, it doesn't fix the problem. Thank you for trying. Still no header.

Comment: @Michael, OK time for some debug. Add the `alerts` as showed in the edited answer and let me know the three alert messages you now see. 5 seconds are too much time, half a second is more than enough. :)

Comment: very cool technique. the first alert was the string. The second alert showed "title: hello" (as you'd expect). The third alert said H1 count 0.  Does that mean there are really zero, or does that 0 represent the first one (i.e. indexes start counting from zero)

Comment: @Michael actually it's not really cool, it's considered old school - but I don't care as it's simple and it works. Anyhow, change `alert("H1 count..` to be this instead: `alert($('#container').html())` - what do you see now in the third alert? The zero you saw means that (at least in jQuery eyes) the document contains no `H1` elements at all so let's dig deeper.

Comment: the third alert shows this unordered list:   <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="consulting-clinic.html">Consulting Clinic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="on-call.html">On Call</a></li>
                        <li><a href="development.html">Development</a></li>
                    </ul>

Comment: @Michael sorry my bad, it's not relevant. Instead, add `id` to the header: `<h1 id="myHeader">Jonathan Stark</h1>` then have this debug code instead: `alert($("#myHeader"));` - what is the result now?

Comment: the alert was [object Object]

Comment: @Michael - good. Hopefully final debug: `alert($("#myHeader").get(0).nodeName);`

Comment: I tried it 3 times. The first two alerts came as usual, but the third one never did.

Comment: @Michael - sure you added the `id` to the element? Anyway try this then: `alert("my header length: " + $("#myHeader").length);` - what are the results now?

Comment: the id was added to the header in iphone.html.  I will try the new alert now thanks.

Comment: header length was 0.  I don't think this would be relevant, but just so you know, the book/source code that I'm using is for JQuery 1.3.2, which is installed on my server.

Comment: @Michael - wait... where does the jQuery code you have is located? In what file?

Comment: JQuery 1.3.2 (which I downloaded with the source code from the book) is in its own file in the server, and is linked to by both html files that you see in the OP, as was done by the book author.

Comment: Sorry @Michael I'm at a loss here. Can't figure out how the JS code can't identify your elements. Will try to think of other options..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard ... problem solved. I was loading the wrong page (the wrong page was automatically being loaded in my browser).  sorry for wasting your time.  I did learn a lot from you so thank you.

Comment: @Michael yeah I figured this was the case just was at a loss how to find what page and how to prove it. Thanks for coming back and sharing this and glad it wasn't all for nothing! :)